# Bash: "Failed to parse arguments" caused by "Text ended before matching quote was found"

Tags: bash, shell

**Goal:**

Run `gnome-terminal -e "npm run start --prefix /home/cc/Desktop/Programming/Software/Elastic/elasticsearch-head"`

**Code:**

```
HEAD="gnome-terminal -e \"npm run start --prefix /home/cc/Desktop/Programming/Software/Elastic/elasticsearch-head\""
${HEAD}
```

**Error:**

Failed to parse arguments: Argument to "--command/-e" is not a valid command: Text ended before matching quote was found for ". (The text was '"npm')

**Additional info:**

When I try to use

```
ES="gnome-terminal -e \"/home/cc/Desktop/Programming/Software/Elastic/pna/bin/elasticsearch\""
${ES}
```

then it works without problem. The difference is that `[...]/bin/elasticsearch` is a shell script itself, while `npm run start` is supposed to run the programm `npm` with the arguments `run start`. But with my non-existing knowledge of Bash I'm not able to solve this.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Here's the obligatory link to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are always used by shell interpreter to detect and protect words. They never be included into the the result

Therefore use an array:

```
HEAD=( gnome-terminal -e "npm run start --prefix \
    /home/cc/Desktop/Programming/Software/Elastic/elasticsearch-head" )
"${HEAD[@]}"
```

Comment: works, thanks. There is a parenthesis missing at the end of the array. Can't edit your reply, because the edit is blocked for being too short.

Comment: Closing parenthesis added!